# Transmitting jwt with POST, from server1 to server2, not working

Tags: javascript, post, jwt

I'm trying to transmit a jwt from server1.js to server2.js in the header of the request.POST; however, I get the following error from server2:

> JsonWebTokenError : jwt must be provided

I'm providing the `jwt` in both my body and header, with Postman. 
What is causing the issue? How do I fix it? Is this the proper syntax to transmit with a JSON header?

---

(server1 - console)

```
token: { actor: 'LOG_SERVER',
[stdout]   description: 'admin',
[stdout]   country: 'Canada',
[stdout]   ids: 
[stdout]    [ { id: 1508959916,
[stdout]        signature: '4d4a542f-d738-4736-8df5-84575b4d90' } ] }
[stdout] token[ids]: [ { id: 1508959916,
[stdout]     signature: '4d4a542f-d738-4736-8df5-84575b4d90' } ]
[stdout] - before request.post
[stdout] after verifyDCS
[stdout] start respondWithJSON
[stdout] end log/asset/audit
[stdout] undefined
```

---

(server1.js)

```
logServer.post('/log/asset/audit/', function(req,res){ 
console.log('--- starting log/asset/audit');
let assetID = req.jwtPayload.assetID;
let dcList = req.jwtPayload.datacenters; //DC from proxy's jwtPayload

logDB.collection('logs').find(  {"transaction.assetID" : assetID, "transaction.type": "Upload"} ).toArray( (err, result) => {

    let token = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self_jwt_body)); 

    result.forEach(function(element, index, array) {    
        console.log('- starting result.forEach function');

        let dcFromLog = element.transaction.dataCenter; //DC from mongodb
        console.log(`dcFromLog: ${dcFromLog}`);
        //take destination dc from these types of transactions
        console.log(`element.transaction.type: ${element.transaction.type}`);

        token["ids"]=[{
            id : element._id,
            signature: element.transaction.signature
            //transactionSignature: element.transactionSignature
        }];

        let JSON_token = JSON.stringify(token);

        console.log('token:', token);
        console.log('token[ids]:', token['ids']);

        console.log('- before request.post');

        request.post({ //**HERE**
            url: dc_link, //includes dc_IP, dc_port and /audit
            headers: 
                {     
                json : {"jwt": jwt.sign({JSON_token}, jwtSecret) } , //**HERE

        }, function(error,response,body){
            if(error || (response.statusCode != 200)){
                console.log((error ? error : body));
                console.log("response:", response);
                console.log("body:", body);
                console.log("error in request.post");
                return;
            }
            console.log("url:", dc_link);
            //console.log(jwt.sign(token, jwtSecret, {expiresIn: '1h'}));
            if(body.result != 0){
                console.log("Error: " + body.description);
            }
        }
        });


    //respond with array of logs.
    respondWithJSON(200, req.body.result, req.body.description, res, result);
    console.log('end log/asset/audit');
  });
});
```

---

(server2.js)

```
function authentication(req,res,next){
    console.log('start authentication'); 
    jwt.verify(req.get('jwt'),jwtSecret, function(err, decoded){ //**HERE
        if(err){
            if(err.name == "TokenExpiredError"){
                respondWithJSON(401, 401, "Authorization expired.", res);
            }else{
                respondWithJSON(400, 400, err.name+" : "+err.message, res);
            }
            console.log(err.name + " : " + err.message);
            return;
        }else{
            req.jwtPayload = decoded;
            next();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `json` sub-key in `headers`? Should it be `headers: { jwt: jwt.sign... }`?

Comment: When I remove the json tag as suggested, it fixes the issue with the jwt!